# Search by probabilistic fields in Xapian and Python

Tags: python, xapian

Here's what I intend to do:

```
doc = xapian.Document()
doc.set_data(somedata)
..
..
doc.add_term("Ajohn doe")
```

Assume the prefix "author" is available for document author.

Now I want to be able to run this search "**searchterm AND author:john doe**"

This is obviously not working because "doe" is being considered part of the author (the QueryParser is translating it to **"searchterm AND author:john OR doe"**). Should I do this:

```
doc.add-term("Ajohn_doe")
```

and search by "**searchterm AND author:john_doe**"? Are there any alternatives for searching text with spaces in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of doing this would be to add terms `Ajohn` and `Adoe` (probably using Xapian's `TermGenerator`, which will do word splitting and term creation for you). Having done this, you can then run a search `author:"john doe"` (a prefixed phrase search, which will be able to search across multiple terms). Something like the following:

```
import xapian
db = xapian.WritableDatabase("my-db", xapian.DB_CREATE_OR_OPEN)
tg = xapian.TermGenerator()

doc = xapian.Document()
tg.set_document(doc)
tg.index_text("John Doe", 1, "A")
db.add_document(doc)

qp = xapian.QueryParser()
qp.add_prefix("author", "A")
q = qp.parse_query('author:"John Doe"')

enq = xapian.Enquire(db)
enq.set_query(q)
for match in enq.get_mset(0, 10):
    print "%8.8i: %f" % (match.docid, match.weight,)
```

(Tested against a semi-recent Xapian trunk, although I don't believe anything is particularly new here.)